# OData .Net: Load relationship objects after initial load

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, odata

What is the best approach for loading the relationship objects of an object I have already obtained through Odata? I understand the .expand() method works for the initial call, but I do not know the type of the object when I make my initial call. Here's a simplified version of my object structure

```
public class BaseClass
{
    long id;
}

public class SubClassWithRelationship : BaseClass
{
    List<OtherClass> OtherClasses;
}

public class OtherClass : BaseClass
{
    string OtherProperty;
}
```

My initial query does not know the type of the derived class it will retrieve. Once it has retrieved it, what is the best way to populate OtherClasses? I imagine I have 3 options

1. Reload the entire object and use the Expand() method (not awesome because I have to load the same data twice).
2. Load the relationship objects and just add them to the object (not my favorite as I wanted to rely on the foreign key relationships).
3. Some unknown method that loads the relationships.

Comment: You can use context.LoadProperty method to load all the related objects.

Comment: @Pratik Thanks! I'm getting an error (with the ever-so-helpful message of "An error occurred") while trying to load the property still, but I think this sends me in the right direction.

Comment: After turning on verbose errors, I found that I had just not set my max version correctly to use LoadProperty. Afterwards it worked great.